# Search for empty string field in Sunspot (Solr)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

In my model, I'm simply using something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :middle_name
  end
end
```

The particular object I'm trying to search for has a :middle_name attribute that contains '', an empty string and is of the String datatype. Based on that information, I am assuming that Sunspot is also saving an empty string for that field in the Solr index.

After successfully doing `Person.reindex` and `Sunspot.commit`, I tried searching for the said object using `Person.search{with(:middle_name, '')}.results`in the rails console and it returns a 400 error in regards to Solr query syntax.

I then looked around and found some information on a query like `Person.search{with(:middle_name, "* TO ''")}.results` and `Person.search{without(:middle_name, "* TO *")}.results`, both of which return an empty set: `[]`.

Anyone know a way that actually works and/or what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Use `Utils.escape` to make the code above work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you have make monkey patch `Sunspot::Query::Restriction::EqualTo` method. Create a new file in config/initializers directory and add this code:

```
module Sunspot
    module Query
      module Restriction

          class EqualTo < Base
              def to_positive_boolean_phrase
                  case @value
                  when nil
                     "#{escape(@field.indexed_name)}:[* TO *]"
                  when ''
                     %Q(#{escape(@field.indexed_name)}:[* TO ""])
                  else
                     super
                  end
               end

               def negated?
                  if @value.nil?
                      !super
                  else
                      super
                  end
               end

               private

               def to_solr_conditional
                   "#{solr_value}"
               end

           end
       end
    end
end
```

Remember to restart rails server before you try this.

Comment: I used this in particular: http://pastebin.com/nwRFMwX6. I haven't taken the time to actually think about what it does, but it works.

Comment: its giving "undefined method `escape' for #<Sunspot::Query::Restriction::EqualTo:0x007fb5114bdb88>"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
person = Person.solr_search do
           keywords params[:middle_name] 
         end

person.results

If you want to try in console then, replace params[:middle_name] 
with middle name of your choice. eg 'burger'
```